# Is there a way to color the row of a selected cell via css?

Tags: css, javafx, tableview

In My TableView with CellSelection enabled i would like to Color the Selected Cell in Light-Blue and the Row of the Selected Cell in Dark-Blue.

I can put this into the RowListener. This Works but drains Performance because i need to Reload the Rows when the selection of cells changes.

In Css i can do:

```
.table-row:selected {
    -fx-background-color: #005797;
}
.table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: #009097;
}
```

But this only works for the Row with RowSelection and for the Cell with CellSelection.

Is there a way to do both in css for CellSelection?

Comment: @Jeremy it's javafx, not html :)